# Get request from RazorPage with ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I tray use ViewComponent in Razor Page with condition,
and each Viewcomponents are separate,
My razorpage is "/Subfolder/Index.cshtml"

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("RightMenu")
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    @if (Model.SIndex != 0)
    {
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("SubContent", new { id = Model.SIndex })

    }

    @if (Model.SIndex == 15)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form method="post">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("QuestionUs", new { askLibrarian = new Lib.Model.AskLibrarian() })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="ask Question" class="btn btn-default" asp-page-handler="question" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    }


</div>
```

and code behind of this is "/subfolder/index.cshtml.cs"

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Lib.Model.LibContext _context;
    [BindProperty]
    public int SIndex { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGet(int Id)
    {
            SIndex = Id;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public AskLibrarian AskLibrarian { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostquestionAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.AskLibrarians.Add(AskLibrarian);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Now "questionViewcomponent" is a simple form that show many input elements
in "/subfolder/component/questionus/default.cshtml"

```
@model Lib.Model.AskLibrarian

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="LibraryNameId" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <select asp-for="LibraryNameId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.LibraryNameId"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label asp-for="Subject" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Text" class="form-control" style="min-height:250px;"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

set breakpoint on "OnpostQuestionAsync", When I click on submit button with "question" handler do nothing and show me a blank page instead question form. 
how can I resolve That

Comment: try to delete this  asp-page-handler="question"

Comment: Change your handler name `OnPostquestionAsync` to `OnPostQuestionAsync`

Comment: Dear Alaaeddine HFIDHI, tray but not working

Comment: Dear Xueli Chen, try it again but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long Time my problem resolved by remove

```
 <input type="submit" value="ask Question" class="btn btn-default" asp-page-handler="question" />
```

and add in form tag

```
<form method="post" sp-page-handler="question">
```